# Is there a way to show the month names of the calendar on the top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Let's say if a month(eg:June -2016) is selected from datepicker of JQuery.It shows 
29th of May to 2nd of July.Here I want to restrict the number of weeks to 4. So I want to change the heading as May-29 To Jun-25.Thus it follows for the other months.

**Html**

```
<h4>
Fiscal Year
</h4>
<input type="text" id="mydatepicker" />
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#mydatepicker").datepicker({
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true
    });
})
```

[image]

<kbd>[Updated Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/qvut8npk/)</kbd>

Comment: You using jQuery datepicker ?

Comment: @Sami Yes I am using JQuery datepicker.

Answer (score 2):

My first idea on how you could address your problem is:

```js
$(function () {
  var defaultMonth = null;
  $("#mydatepicker").datepicker({
    showOtherMonths: true,
    monthNames: [ "Dec-29 To Jan-25",  "Jan-29 To Feb-25", "Feb-29 To Mar-25", "Mar-29 To Apr-25", "Apr-29 To May-25",
                 "May-29 To Jun-25", "Jun-29 To Jul-25", "Jul-29 To Aug-25", "Aug-29 To Sep-25",
                 "Sep-29 To Oct-25", "Oct-29 To Nov-25", "Nov-29 To Dec-25"],
    onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
      var newDate = new Date(year, month - 1, 29);
      $(this).datepicker('setDate', newDate);
    }
  });

  $("#mydatepicker").datepicker('widget').on('DOMNodeInserted', '.ui-datepicker-calendar', function(e) {
    // reduce the number of weeks to 4
    while ($(this).find('tr').length > 5) {
      $(this).find('tr:last').remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div.ui-datepicker {
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 20em;
}

.ui-datepicker-week-end, .ui-datepicker-week-end a.ui-state-default {
  color: red;
}
.ui-priority-secondary, .ui-widget-content .ui-priority-secondary, .ui-widget-header .ui-priority-secondary{
  font-weight:bold;
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<h4>
    Fiscal Year
</h4>
<input type="text" id="mydatepicker" />
```

Let me know if this first draft could start to help you....

Comment: The dates in the heading do not match with the dates in that view.Also the dates are missing from the july month.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know whether you like my way or not, yet tried to find you a solution
My way was to edit jquery.ui.js directly. And edited it. For now its been uploaded to a private server of mine. Once if this is the answer you were seaching for then i will try to upload it in git or any public server.
Download link [jquery.ui.js](http://techrk.com/stackOverflow/) .please up vote if this is what you were looking for else comment me .Thanks ~Nr

check again. i have updated the UI glitch it had

and if u need to make title in single line then add the below css in ur code

```
<style>
 #dtpTitle
 {
  font-size: small;

 }
</style>
```

Comment: I am unable to check that. I can't download any files. Try to make a fiddle and paste the link. Can you make a fiiddle ?

Comment: you can add yours in the external resources on the left side.[fiiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115064/discussion-between-hazard-and-nair-ranjith).

Comment: Where did you paste the link ?

Comment: copy that link and paste it here

Comment: @NairRanjith - did this ever get answered? If so, you may consider marking one of the answers as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution, hide last row with

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#mydatepicker").datepicker({
      showOtherMonths: true,
      selectOtherMonths: true
  });

  // add this below lines to get required output
  $("#mydatepicker").click(function(){
     $("table.ui-datepicker-calendar tr:last").hide();
  })

})
```

Comment: if I hide the row,the dates will be missed.I want the next row to appear with  the next month.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your expected result, use below option

1.Get previous month and first date

```
     $("#mydatepicker").datepicker('widget').on('DOMNodeInserted', '.ui-datepicker-calendar', function(event) {
   var currMonth = $('.ui-datepicker-title .ui-datepicker-month')[0].innerHTML;
    var currIndex = months.indexOf(currMonth);
    var lastDate = $('a.ui-state-default')[27].innerHTML;
    var year = $('.ui-datepicker-title .ui-datepicker-year')[0].innerHTML;
    var prev = months[currIndex - 1] + ' ' + $('.ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-default.ui-priority-secondary')[0].innerHTML;
    console.log(prev);
    $('.ui-datepicker-title').prepend('<span>' + prev + '-</span>');
    $('.ui-datepicker-year').html('<span>' + lastDate + ' ' + year + '</span>');

    $('.ui-datepicker-calendar tr:last').remove();
```

2.Adding it to the title and removing last row

```
  $('.ui-datepicker-title').prepend('<span>' + prev + '-</span>');
    $('.ui-datepicker-year').html('<span>' + lastDate + ' ' + year + '</span>');

    $('.ui-datepicker-calendar tr:last').remove();
```

Codepen-http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/dXpmKm

Comment: Dates of current month and previous months looks fine....Hope this works for you :)

Comment: No.Dates are missing as we move to next monts

Comment: Also 5 weeks are coming with wrong heading.Eg:In june-July month view